# Take a picture in android HTML app with InAppBrowser or iFrame

Tags: android, html, iframe, android-camera, inappbrowser

The scenario is as follows: I have a website with an input type file that works correctly in Android default browser, chrome and firefox. I'm using ionic to embed the website into an app and everything goes fine but taking picture. The thing I just can't understand is the option video recording works, even voice recording but not taking a photo...

Till now I have tried with InAppBrowser where the button doesn't work at all, with an iframe which is the best approach allowing the user to select a file or to record a sound and with a plugin called Crosswalk WebView Engine, which allow me to record a video or to select an image but I just need the picture and can't find a way to do it.

This is happening in all android versions I've found, 4.1.2, 5.0.2 and 6.

I know there are some other threads out there about this topic but any of them have helped me.

In the website part I've tried all kind of combinations I know:

```
<input type="file" name="new-image">
<input type="file" name="new-image" accept="image/*">
<input type="file" name="new-image" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
<input type="file" name="new-image" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
<input type="file" name="new-image" capture="camera">
```

Even (out of desperation)

```
<input type="file" name="new-image" accept="image/jpg;capture=camera">
```

Any help will be highly appreciated...

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right,u are using hybrid app, so i suggest u to use this plugin https://github.com/mbppower/CordovaCameraPreview
I used this plugin in one of my app ,u can take picture or run in background as well, also there is a example app for this plugin
https://github.com/mbppower/CordovaCameraPreviewApp
u can understand how it works with this example it works on android and ios very well

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the app just load an external website using its inputs and forms, as if you were using chrome or something, no separate code, I think I can't use that...Tell me if I'm wrong and thanks again...